# How to Calculate the Precision Required to Exactly Produce the Repeating Sequence of Digits in the Decimal Expansion of a Fraction

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation, rounding-error, machine-precision

Say I am given a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ and wish to express it as a decimal such that the repeating sequence of digits is accurately displayed at least once and preferably twice in the printed output. How would I calculate the machine-precision required in order to do this?

Comment: I think we need more information here. In particular, why must you use finite precision arithmetic? Realistically, you are limited to IEEE single and double precision. The  repeating sequence of digits can be arbitrarily long. In particular, it can be longer than the number of significant figures you can represent. A routine which implements division between arbitrarily long integers would solve your problem in general.

Comment: @CarlChristian there are computer languages (scheme and haskell come to mind) that support rationals so you don't get the imprecision of the floats.

Comment: @QthePlatypus. You are right. Reflecting on the question it occurred to me that it was the OP's choice of the word "machine precision" which lead me to assume that the use of floating point numbers was required. I remain puzzled by the question. One could compute the digits of the decimal expansion one digit at a time using, say, single precision arithmetic (or less) as one would do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

One way of dealing with this would be to consult the sequence https://oeis.org/A051626 this is the Period of decimal representation of 1/q and the period of p/q should be limited at at least this length.